# Wordpress on Azure - Invalid format for email address: WordPress on Azure Click here for more support

Tags: wordpress, azure

I have a new Wordpress site that I have created on my Azure Subscription.

Its running Woocommerce with an Auction plugin.

It seems to work fine but the mailer alerts for bids, out bids and others are not being sent to the sender with the above error.

Other emails, such as user account creation do work fine however, any ideas please?

Javier.

As above I expected email alerts to be sent to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same problem. I used Post SMTP plugin. First it couldn't send any emails. I changed the plugin settings to use PHP_Mailer instead of PostSMTP email function. Then it worked. Even Elementor submission emails are now sent to my Gmail.